# Add value in a new col if element present into a list in R

Tags: r

Hello I have two df such as

```
liste<-c("seq2","seq3")
```

df1

```
COL1 COL2 
seq1 A
seq2 B
seq3 C
seq4 D
seq5 E
```

and I  would like to add ok in a new `COL3`if the `COL1`value is present in the `liste`

and get :

```
COL1 COL2 COL3
seq1 A    NA
seq2 B    OK
seq3 C    OK
seq4 D    NA
seq5 E    NA
```

So far I tried a loop but it takes a lot of time:

```
df$COL3<-NA
nb<-1
for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if(df[row, "COL1"] %in% liste){
    df$COL3[nb]<-"OK"
  }
  nb<-nb+1
}
```

Comment: `df1$COL3 <- ifelse(df1$COL1 %in% liste, "OK", NA)`

Comment: `df %>% mutate(COL3 = COL1 %in% liste)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `%in%` to add `COL3`

```
within(df, COL3 <- c(NA,"OK")[COL1 %in% liste + 1])
```

which gives

```
  COL1 COL2 COL3
1 seq1    A <NA>
2 seq2    B   OK
3 seq3    C   OK
4 seq4    D <NA>
5 seq5    E <NA>
```